# grep -f file search

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have two files. the first (`file1.txt`) has about 15,000 lines and the second file (`file2.txt`) has about 180,000 lines. I am trying to find all of the matching lines from `file1.txt` and remove them from `file2.txt`. What I am currently trying is this:

```
grep -v -f file1.txt file2.txt > out.txt
```

This does work, but takes an extremely long time. I am trying to find a way to speed this up, but am having trouble figuring it out. Does anyone have a suggestions?
Thank for your help

Comment: "match" you meant here is identical right? not regex match?

Comment: @Kent Because OP is using `grep`, I suppose he wants to do regexp (or at least partial text) match

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/perls-equivalent-of-grep-f.html or http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the definition of "match" here is "identical":

try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;}!($0 in a)' file1 file2 >out.txt
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works perfectly and almost instantly. awk can do alot of cool stuff, that I need to learn...Thank you

Comment: @user1352084, can you try your grep line, but with -F option, it looks like `grep -F -v -f file1 fil2` to see if it is faster?

Comment: @user1352084 since it solved your issue, accept the answer please

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  I don't know what the !(...) means

Comment: @DanielKaplan the thing in () is a boolean expression, if $0 from file2 in array "a". the ! outside is NOT like not(true/false)